# Splash Screen sliding effect in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using **`react-native-navigation`** for navigation and **`react-native-smart-splash-screen`** for generating splash screen.

It successfully implemented the splash screen but now what i want is the **sliding effect** (slide in from right) instead of **fade out**.

is there any way to customize it ?

any suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Comment: it says that the `animationType: determine the type of animation. enum(animationType.none, animationType.fade, animationType.scale)`. So no there's no other way but to play with its source code.

Comment: any custom module for this purpose ? @Raymond